# Future predictions payment amount program

Tags: java

I'm working on a program to estimate the future tuition fee for an institution as it increases by 7% yearly, so how many years will it take to double the amount.
Let's say the current amount is $10000

Here is my Java code:

```
public class FutureTuition{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       double tuition = 10000;
       //7% of tuition = 7/100 * 10000 = 700
        Int year = 1;

        while(tuition < 20000){
                tuition = tuition+700;
                year++;
     }

     System.out.println("Tuition will be doubled in " + year + " years");}}
```

The result was :
Tuition will be doubled in 16 years

I don't think that's right,what's wrong?

Comment: *I don't think that's right* - you really should make sure before you post here. As it stands you don't even know if you have a problem

Comment: `year` should start at 0

Comment: That the number is wrong is pretty obvious. 
10.000 * 1.07 ^ x >= 20.000 

Take logarithm:

log 10.000 + x * log 1.07 >= log 20.000

Isolate x:
x = (log(20000) − log(10000)) ÷ log(1,07)

=> x = 10,244

Comment: Okay, but my problem here is how the 7% became 1.07 instead of 0.07

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue you're having isn't about the code, but rather the question being asked. That is not something the SO community can help answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost right. Just the increasement rate must be 1.07*tuition, not 700 flat every time. Which Java version did you use? This works with 1.8.

```
public class FutureTuition{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double tuition = 10000;
        //7% of tuition = 7/100 * 10000 = 700
        Integer year = 0;

        while(tuition < 20000){
            tuition = tuition * 1.07;
            year++;
        }

        System.out.println("Tuition will be doubled in " + year + " years");}

}
```

Comment: please note that I very recently changed the code. The year must indeed start with 0, not 1.

Comment: My question is about the code,when I use 1.07 in the increment as recommended it worked fine,but I need to be briefed why it's so.

Comment: If you add 700$ the first time, your tuition has increased to 10700. So if you now add 7%, you must ask yourself: 7% of what? Of the original amount 10000 or of the new amount 10700? This is an interest-on-interest situation.

Comment: Wikipedia on compound interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest 
What you calculated was the simple interest.

Comment: Simple interest: 10000 -> 10700 -> 11400 -> ...
Compound interest: 10000 -> 10700 -> 11449 -> ...

Comment: Thanks,I got it now

Comment: That's great, you're welcome. Have a nice day.